# How to make python bot reply to the same number in list

Tags: python

If for example I did a code like this:
Greet = [“hello”, “hi”]
Keyword = [“hi”, “hello”]
How do I make it so I send the same list number? For example hello would be 0 on the Greet list so I would send hi as it is 0 on the keyword list?

Comment: Please add minimal readable code and rephrase your question.

Comment: user = user(input("what would you like to say?: "))
greetings = ["hi", "hello", "yo"]
keywords = ["Hi!", "Hello!", "Yo!"]
while user != "bye": (end of code) How would I make it so if what the user says is hi which is 1 on my list my program says Hi! Which is also 1 on my other list

Comment: You can edit your question to update it with the code, see "Edit" button under your post

Comment: Why use two lists instead of a dictionary?

Comment: Use `index()` to get the position of the input in `keywords`. Then send the corresponding element of `greetings`.

Answer (score 1):

This would be what you have in mind:

```
greetings = ["hi", "hello", "yo"]
keywords = ["Hi!", "Hello!", "Yo!"]

while True:

    user = input("what would you like to say?: ")

    if user == "bye":
        break

    try:
        print(keywords[greetings.index(user)])
    except ValueError:
        print('I don\'t know how to reply.')
```

More pythonic would be:

```
answers = {"hi": "Hi!",
           "hello": "Hello!",
           "yo": "Yo!"}

while True:
    
    user = input("what would you like to say?: ")
    
    if user == "bye":
        break
    
    try:
        print(answers[user])
    except KeyError:
        print('I don\'t know how to reply')
```

or:

```
from collections import defaultdict

answers = defaultdict(lambda:'I don\'t know how to reply.')
answers.update({"hi": "Hi!",
                "hello": "Hello!",
                "yo": "Yo!"})

while True:
    user = input("what would you like to say?: ")
    if user == "bye":
        break
    print(answers[user])
```